# Chev Spark 1.2 using water , no leaks evident. Car runs fine and driving in 30° c heat.hecked all over. Car runs fine

Tags: cooling-system, cooling

Cooling system using liquid daily. No leaks evident n car runs fine.

Comment: How much coolant is being lost each day?  Coolant has to go somewhere.  A couple of easy things you can check. With the car running is there an abundance of white smoke coming from your tailpipe?  Have you checked your engine oil dipstick to see if it looks like a milkshake which would indicate coolant has mixed with your oil.  You can also take it to your local mechanic and he can pressure test your coolant system and likely identify the leak pretty quickly.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

The usual cause of this is a blown head gasket that is allowing coolant to pass from the cooling system and into the combustion chamber and then out the tailpipe.

Other possible causes are a warped or cracked cylinder head or a cracked block.